# Displaying HTML elements depending on which link is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just started learning web development a few days ago and I wanted to create a simple page to get my feet wet. I wanted to have a top navigation bar and depending on which one was clicked certain HTML elements would be displayed. I used a switch statement to turn off all other elements and only display the one in question.

For some reason however, it is not behaving as expected.

Here is my HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <title>Care and Advice Clinic</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="backend.js"></script>
  <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "stylesheet.css">
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="javascript: StateMachine(1); return false;">
      Contact and Address
    </a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="javascript: StateMachine(2); return false;">
      Operation Times
    </a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="javascript: StateMachine(3); return false;">
      About
    </a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="javascript: StateMachine(4); return false;">
      School of Diabetes
    </a></li>
  </ul>
  <h1 style = "font-size: 40px; padding-top: 30px;"> Diabetes Care and Advice</h1>
  <p id="Debug" style="font-size: 60px;"></p>
  <p id="Contact" style="font-size: 60px;">
    You have clicked on Contact and Address
  </p>
  <p id="OpTimes">You have clicked on OpTimes</p>
  <p id="About">You have clicked on About</p>
  <p id="School">You have clicked on School</p>
  <script>javascript: StateMachine(0);</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my javascript code:

```js
//The states are Contact (1), OperationTimes (2), About(3), School(4), home(0)
StateMachine(index);

function StateMachine(index){

  switch(index){

    case 0:
      document.getElementById("Debug").innerHTML = "Switch case 0 entered";
      document.getElementById("Optimes").style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById("About").style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById("School").style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById("Contact").style.display = 'none';
      break;

    case 1:
      document.getElementById("Debug").innerHTML = "Switch case 1 entered";
      document.getElementById("Optimes").style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById("About").style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById("School").style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById("Contact").style.display = 'block';
      break;

    case 2:
      document.getElementById("Debug").innerHTML = "Switch case 2 entered";
      document.getElementById("Contact").style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById("About").style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById("School").style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById("OpTimes").style.display = 'block';
      break;

    case 3:
      document.getElementById("Debug").innerHTML = "Switch case 3 entered";
      document.getElementById("Contact").style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById("Optimes").style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById("School").style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById("About").style.display = 'block';
      break;

    case 4:
      document.getElementById("Debug").innerHTML = "Switch case 4 entered";
      document.getElementById("Contact").style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById("Optimes").style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById("About").style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById("School").style.display = 'block';
      break;
  }


}
```

It prints out the debug msg so document.getElementById("Debug").innerHTML = "Switch case 0 entered"; works but the rest of the switch statement isn't executed.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Seems to be working for me, do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: The elements are being displayed when they shouldn't be unless i clicked on the respective links. Are you not getting the same thing as me?

Comment: Sorry, I was too early to judge, like both answers say, you need to change the capital `T` to a lower `t` in your HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this code in Firefox 54 and it worked for me. Nevertheless i go a error message, because `OpTimes` is defined with a large T in your HTML code. Unify your code and it should work. Replace all occurances with `OpTimes` or with `Optimes`.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `<p id="OpTimes">You have clicked on OpTimes</p>` to **`<p id="Optimes">You have clicked on OpTimes</p>`**.

This element's id should be **`Optimes`** not **`OpTimes`**